# Library for distributed spring config (outside springboot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper

I am looking for solution for distributed spring configuration. I am thinking of storing it in zookeeper. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper does have that functionality but apparently it requires to use `spring-boot`.

Is there any similar library that I can use outside `spring-boot`

Answer (score 0):

### [Consul by HashiCorp](https://www.consul.io/)

Consul is a popular option because it is:

- Open Source
- Includes Service Discovery & Configuration
- Support Multi-Datacenter out of the box
- Etc.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require you to use Spring Boot, it just provides the auto-configurations in case you **do** decide to go with Spring Boot. In other words, if you're not using Spring Boot, none of the configurations will apply automatically, you'll have to provide the configuration yourself.

Zookeeper is a good option, go for it.

**EDIT:**
To use Zookeeper without Spring Boot, you'd need to register the appropriate beans either manually or by importing the auto-configuration classes that Spring Boot would import for you implicitly. This rule of thumb generally applies to all Spring Boot-enabled modules.

In your case, you'd most likely need to import just the `ZookeeperConfigBootstrapConfiguration` and `ZookeeperConfigAutoConfiguration`. The classes are to be found within `spring-cloud-zookeeper-config` module so no Spring Boot dependencies needed.

Alternatively, you should look at those classes and their `@Import`s and declare the beans manually.

Comment: is there a documentation/example I can look at  on how to use it outside spring-boot

Comment: I tried adding following two beans in spring beans xml 

    
    <bean class="org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.config.ZookeeperConfigBootstrapConfiguration"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.ZookeeperAutoConfiguration"/>
    

but I am running into two problems. 
* properties from my `application.yamlo` with prefix `spring.cloud.zookeeper` are not getting parsed 
* bean for `PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration` is not getting created and hence is not reading properties from zookeeper.

Comment: That's because you're missing BootstrapApplicationListener in your context, try adding that, too. Also, Zookeeper Config does not read from `application.properties/yml` but from `bootstrap.properties/yml`.

Comment: @ Miloš Milivojević - Thank you for the suggestion. Looks like this whole thing is too tightly wired with `spring-boot` and seems like it can't be done outside `spring-boot`

Comment: Simply not true: it can't be done with a few lines perhaps but you can take the longer road - registering the beans manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for using spring-cloud-zookeeper without Spring Boot, based on the idea provided here https://wenku.baidu.com/view/493cf9eba300a6c30d229f49.html

First, create a CloudEnvironement class that will create a PropertySource from Zookeeper :

**CloudEnvironement.java**

```
  public class CloudEnvironment extends StandardServletEnvironment { 

  @Override 
  protected void customizePropertySources(MutablePropertySources propertySources) { 
    super.customizePropertySources(propertySources); 
    try { 
      propertySources.addLast(initConfigServicePropertySourceLocator(this)); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { 
      logger.warn("failed to initialize cloud config environment", ex); 
    } 
  } 

  private PropertySource<?> initConfigServicePropertySourceLocator(Environment environment) { 
    ZookeeperConfigProperties configProp = new ZookeeperConfigProperties(); 
    ZookeeperProperties props = new ZookeeperProperties(); 
    props.setConnectString("myzookeeper:2181"); 
    CuratorFramework fwk = curatorFramework(exponentialBackoffRetry(props), props); 
    ZookeeperPropertySourceLocator propertySourceLocator = new ZookeeperPropertySourceLocator(fwk, configProp); 
    PropertySource<?> source= propertySourceLocator.locate(environment); 
    return source ; 
  } 

  private CuratorFramework curatorFramework(RetryPolicy retryPolicy, ZookeeperProperties properties) { 
    CuratorFrameworkFactory.Builder builder = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder(); 
    builder.connectString(properties.getConnectString()); 
    CuratorFramework curator = builder.retryPolicy(retryPolicy).build(); 
    curator.start(); 
    try { 
      curator.blockUntilConnected(properties.getBlockUntilConnectedWait(), properties.getBlockUntilConnectedUnit()); 
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) { 
      throw new RuntimeException(e); 
    } 
    return curator; 
  } 

  private RetryPolicy exponentialBackoffRetry(ZookeeperProperties properties) { 
    return new ExponentialBackoffRetry(properties.getBaseSleepTimeMs(), 
        properties.getMaxRetries(), 
        properties.getMaxSleepMs()); 
  } 

}
```

Then create a custom XmlWebApplicationContext class : it will enable to load the PropertySource from Zookeeper when your webapplication start and replace the bootsrap magic of Spring Boot:

**MyConfigurableWebApplicationContext.java**

```
public class MyConfigurableWebApplicationContext extends XmlWebApplicationContext { 

  @Override 
  protected ConfigurableEnvironment createEnvironment() { 
    return new CloudEnvironment(); 
  } 
}
```

Last, in your **web.xml** file add the following context-param for using your MyConfigurableWebApplicationContext class and bootstraping your CloudEnvironement.

```
<context-param>           
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name> 
      <param-value>com.kiabi.config.MyConfigurableWebApplicationContext</param-value> 
    </context-param>
```

If you use a standard property file configurer, it should still be loaded so you can have properties in both a local file and Zookeeper.

For all this to work you need to have spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config and curator-framework jar in your classpath with their dependancy, if you use maven you can add the following to your **pom.xml**

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-zookeeper-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
            <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```